# MySql On update, select into another table conditionally

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables `posts_app` and `posts_unapp`. Both are same in structure.

**posts_app - contains moderated posts**

```
"id"    "title" "body"  "url"   "user"  "country"
```

**posts_unapp - fresh posts end up here**

```
"id"    "title" "body"  "url"   "user"  "country"   "Status"
1       Hello   Test    Foo     Bar     Tar         2
```

`posts_unapp` contains new posts, which a moderator has not yet approved. New posts are inserted with `status = 2` (which means they have not yet been checked and are neither approved or rejected).

Once a moderator has checked a post, the column `status` is updated to `true` if approved, or `false` if rejected. At this time, is it possible to automatically copy the post to the `posts_app` table only if the status is set to true?

One way of thought of doing this was by using a `trigger on update` on `posts_unapp`. But the problem is, a moderater can set a `status` to `true` or `false`. Both count as updates and both will fire the trigger. Setting `status = flase` need not copy the data, the data needs to be copied only when the the `status` is set to `true`.

What would be a good way to do this? I've decided to use two tables to keep the `posts_app` table clean.

Comment: Is it possible that status in `posts_unapp` can be changed back to 2 and then to false and true (meaning reopen review of a post)?

Comment: Right now, that's not possible. Once it's status is set, it cannot be reopened.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER mytrig AFTER UPDATE ON posts_unapp
    FOR EACH ROW
    BEGIN
        IF NEW.Status = 'true' THEN  
            INSERT INTO posts_app VALUES(NEW.id, NEW.title,NEW.body,NEW.url,NEW.user,NEW.country);
        END IF;
    END;
$$
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: I'm trying this out. Seem to have run into a few problems.

Comment: This works. Thing is the `id` column in `post_app` is `auto increment`. If I leave that out in the trigger, I get `Column count doesn't match value count at row 1`. So I need to use: `INSERT INTO posts_app (title,body,url,user,country) VALUES(NEW.title,NEW.body,NEW.url,NEW.user,NEW.country);` Is that right?